# React which one is better defining an array outside of a component vs inside of a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Outside of a component

```js
const somevalue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const Component = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {somevalue.map((value) => <span>{value}</span>)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

Inside of a component

```js
const Component = () => {
  const somevalue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  return (
    <div>
      {somevalue.map((value) => <span>{value}</span>)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

When I defined fixed value. I defined them outside of a component. I discussed it with my team about it and we decided that we will define them inside of a component. Because we thought that might be one cause of the memory leak. There would be variables in the memory even if we don't use them. (I have been thinking about using dynamic import).
But even if I define them inside of a component, there are still needed spaces for functions, right? That's not even a lot of differences in the length of the letters. I'm not sure what would be the best choice I can take.

Comment: If it's a static array (for example in your example), it's better to define outside, because in that case it won't be "recalculated" on every component re-render. If it's a computed value, or something depending on props and/or state or whatever, you have no choice but define it inside.

Comment: Also keep in mind that proper variable naming notation for constants that you define somewhere on top of file should be `UPPER_CASE`, like `const SOME_VALUE = [...]`.

Comment: Personnaly i prefers to declare it outside if it's a constant as you tagged typescript I'll enforce the immutability of the array (and recursively if needed) : `const SOME_VALUE: readonly number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];` in any other case i'll do it inside of the component (sometimes wrapped in a useMemo ...). IMHO, the point of Functionnal Component and hook stuff is to write purest functions posible so you need to avoid side effect or use of external values as much as possible. Better readability, testability, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your opinions, guys! I can't believe why I wouldn't come up with `readonly` keyword. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference since you are using a static value. If it is not used outside the component, keep it scoped to the component. Performance wise there won't be much of a difference unless it is a large array because runtimes are smart enough to inline them.